# what's the hello world example for using pipe to share resources between processes in c++?

Tags: c++, pipe

Can you list one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is none, because C++ does not provide this functionality as standard. You will have to specify a platform and OS before any code can be shown.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about Named pipes under Windows, you can find an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365588(v=VS.85).aspx).